# Views on identity of an individual

Tags: ethics

I have been wondering for a while that I technically have specific traits of specific people around and have known the fact that humans tend to emulate other people.

My question is that **is it alright for me to have no characteristic that is unique to me** and be kind of like a union of the set of all the properties of others and impersonate parts of their personality?

More over, **should an opinion be held towards a person who lacks individuality and simply does what a set of person(s) say?**

**Edit:** It is not that I don't have a perspective on something. The thing is that it changes when I see somebody else do it. For example, if I see someone else help someone, I feel an urge to help someone too.

PS I am not sure whether this question should be asked on philosophy.stackexchange so, flagging as off-topic might be more helpful than down-votes. And if such is the case, then I really regret having wasted your time.

Comment: personality vampire? i wouldn't take it too seriously

Comment: It sounds like a basic, inborn personality trait commonly known as 'agreeableness', which is a lovely and happy trait usually found in normal young people who are mentally healthy, although it can cause some problems in adults who aren't consciously aware of having it. So this really sounds to me like a Psychology SE question.

Comment: A lot of 'personality' is affectation. Don't sweat it, everyone is a fraud.

Comment: Some would argue it is impossible to be anything other that a (possibly) unique conglomeration of "other peoples" traits: for where would any individual traits come from and how many could there be?- But an awareness of your own tendency to emulate isn't something I've seen any literature on, but then again what, and why, would you write on that? - Anyway, welcome to Philosophy SE!

Comment: honestly @Bread is more or less right (ime of life and so on). you're probably highly agreeable and spending time with great / narcissistic people... "sweat it" if you like?

Comment: It is difficult to know what's off-topic on Phil. SE

Answer (score 1):

The characteristics that one *has* are an objectification into traits or predicates that one can imagine oneself *possessing*. They are only a list of what one has that might be useful for market researchers or sociologists.  No living person is the sum total of these characteristics because that sum total would not be able to experience any of those predicates.

Kenneth T. Gallagher illustrates this by quoting Gabriel Marcel's *Metaphysical Journal*, page 199:

> *I am always and at every moment* more than the totality of predicates that an inquiry made by myself - or by someone else - about myself...would be able to bring to light.

It doesn't matter if we have all these objective characteristics in common.

Here is the question:

> My question is that is it alright for me to have no characteristic that is unique to me and be kind of like a union of the set of all the properties of others and impersonate parts of their personality?

According to Gabriel Marcel, you are more than the sum total of those characteristics. If you accept philosophic positions such as his, it is alright.

---

Kenneth T. Gallagher. *The Philosophy of Gabriel Marcel*. 1975. Fordham University Press. page 55.